# SQL Server function execution - while statement behaviour unexpected

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, while-loop

I'm using this code to remove non numeric characters from a string:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StripNonNumerics](@Temp VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50);
    SET @KeepValues = '%[^0-9]%';

    WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, ''); 
    END

    RETURN @Temp
 END;
```

I expect that if I call this function, putting as input a string like this one:

```
select [dbo].[StripNonNumerics]('vAn34nd2')
```

I could get this output:

```
342
```

Instead, I obtain:

```
3
```

I changed input to test this behaviour, and I noticed that it takes only the first non numeric characters sequence. Could you tell me what I'm overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: [*Bad habits to kick* : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Otherwise, they might end up being a **default length**, which in case of a parameter or return value is **1 CHARACTER** .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the return definition to read:

```
RETURNS varchar(255)
```

If you omit the length, the the default length is 1

Answer (score 2):

I am just adding one another way of doing the above..

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(100)='vAn34nd2', @Y VARCHAR(100)=''

SELECT @Y = @Y+ VAL FROM(
SELECT SUBSTRING(@X,number,1) AS VAL 
FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
WHERE type='P' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@X)
AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@X,number,1))=1
)A

SELECT @Y
```